# Using output of apply fnc in next apply iteration python

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

Below is a 1. starting df (called "close"),and 2. an apply line of code, and its resulting df:

1.

```
Date    
2006-01-27  100.0
2006-01-30  100.0
2006-01-31  100.0
2006-02-01  100.0
2006-02-02  NaN
2006-02-03  NaN
```

2.

```
close.apply(lambda x: x.shift(1) + (x.shift(4))

Date    
2006-01-27  NaN
2006-01-30  NaN
2006-01-31  NaN
2006-02-01  NaN
2006-02-02  100.706786
2006-02-03  NaN
```

My expected output is to use the output from #2 (100.706786) , and the existing df "close" to calculate the next value in the sequence which would be 2/03 . That date requires the last value (shift 1), and 4 values from then (shift 4, or 100).

How do I do this with only vectorization? I want to avoid for loops because it is super slow. Here's the one I have:

```
closedf = pd.DataFrame()
for num,date in enumerate(close.index[4:]):
    widget = close.apply(lambda x: x.shift(1) + (x.shift(4)).iloc[num+4]
    closedf[date] = close.iloc[num+4] = widget
```

Comment: Not 100% sure that's possible in one operation I'm afraid. You basically want to use the result from the previous iteration in the next iteration, without using iteration!

Comment: is there a way to speed up my function?

Comment: mostly unhappy with the time it takes

Comment: Possibly... do you need the apply at all?

Comment: No- there's no rules here hahah

Comment: Alright... so I tried this, and I get 200 as the output of the shift, not 100.70... am I missing something?

Comment: Random idea... try `(close.shift(1) + close.shift(4)).fillna(0).cumsum()`?

Comment: ah yes sorry the equation is much longer on my end, but these two should just give you 200.. so ya thats correct

Comment: ooh okay, one sec

Comment: Hmm... if the equation is more involved, then my solution may not be able to generalise... but I'm not sure. Let me know.

Comment: that one didnt quite work (it just gets 200 for the rest of them), but I like the np.cum fncs idea

Comment: Ah, had a feeling it wouldn't work. One idea would be to speed up the function by removing the apply. I don't think you need it.

Comment: Consider closing out [your other question on this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47214286/using-df-apply-lambda-recursively-in-python).

Answer (score 4):

Consider a series `close`

```
close = pd.Series(
    [100] * 3 + [100.706786] + [np.nan] * 10,
    pd.date_range('2006-01-27', periods=14, name='Date')
)

close

Date
2006-01-27    100.000000
2006-01-28    100.000000
2006-01-29    100.000000
2006-01-30    100.706786
2006-01-31           NaN
2006-02-01           NaN
2006-02-02           NaN
2006-02-03           NaN
2006-02-04           NaN
2006-02-05           NaN
2006-02-06           NaN
2006-02-07           NaN
2006-02-08           NaN
2006-02-09           NaN
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

---

**Solution**
This is a derivative of the fibonacci sequence.  As far as I know, we can't "vectorize" that... (w/e "vectorize" means)

But we can create a generator that performs the task

```
def shib(x1, x2, x3, x4):
    while True:
        x1, x2, x3, x4 = x2, x3, x4, x1 + x4
        yield x4
```

And then use it to assign new vars

```
from itertools import islice

close.iloc[4:] = list(islice(shib(*close[:4]), 0, len(close) - 4))

close

Date
2006-01-27     100.000000
2006-01-28     100.000000
2006-01-29     100.000000
2006-01-30     100.706786
2006-01-31     200.706786
2006-02-01     300.706786
2006-02-02     400.706786
2006-02-03     501.413572
2006-02-04     702.120358
2006-02-05    1002.827144
2006-02-06    1403.533930
2006-02-07    1904.947502
2006-02-08    2607.067860
2006-02-09    3609.895004
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a pretty handy solution (and very fast) using deque:

```
from collections import deque

queue = deque([100]*(4))    
close = []
for num in range(0,len(close.index-4):
    nextval = queue[-1] + queue[0]
    close.append(nextval)
    queue.popleft()
    queue.append(nextval)
close = pd.DataFrame(close,index=close.index)
```